# ionic 3 ion-input inside ion-item height issues

Tags: css, ionic3

i am building a website and the form has input with label. They seems to have too my height and i am unable to figure out how to reduce it. the code looks like

```
  <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col text-right><ion-item no-lines><ion-label class="fa-labels">Name</ion-label><ion-input placeholder="Infrastructure Information" value="Infrastructure Information"></ion-input></ion-item></ion-col>
          <ion-col><ion-item no-lines><ion-label class="fa-labels">Close Date</ion-label><ion-input value="7/15/17"></ion-input></ion-item></ion-col>
        </ion-row>
         <ion-row>
          <ion-col text-right><ion-item no-lines><ion-label class="fa-labels">Account</ion-label><ion-input  value="Net-World Technologies"></ion-input></ion-item></ion-col>
          <ion-col><ion-item no-lines><ion-label class="fa-labels">Status</ion-label><ion-input value="Open"></ion-input></ion-item></ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
```

applied css

```
ion-input {
     border: 0.5px solid #BCC0C2;
     margin: 0px;
     padding:0px;
 }
```

doing a padding or margin didnt help to 0px.

Comment: My device keyboard is not appearing is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<ion-input class="ioninput"> <ion-input>
```

And in CSS:

```
.ioninput{
     input{
         height:xx px;
          }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding the docs correctly, you need to style using classes and not by selecting elements themselves. So...

`<ion-input class="input" ...></ion-input>` and `.input { padding: 0; margin: 0; }`

Comment: hey @JDewitt we need to have a talk, Ive checked some of your answers and I have to say, your code smells.